# my django 3 project is shwoing 'ModelForm has no model class specified'

Tags: django, django-forms

i am a beginner django developer, "ModelForm has no model class specified. " is given on my project , what i can do pls help, i will be greatfull to you if you solve my problem

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import product

class productform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model:product
        fields: '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from formt.forms import productform

def index(request):
    form = productform()

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html' , context )
```

index.html

```
<h1>form model</h1>

<form action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
<input type="submit" text="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

forms.py

```
    class ProductForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
    from .forms import ProductForm
```

Comment: thank you, i was mistaken "=" with " : " , i have understand my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Look at your syntax.
Class names should start with a  capital letter.

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields: '__all__'
```